# Why isn't heapsort lg(n!)?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, heapsort, clrs

I'm reading CLRS and it says heapsort is

```
HEAPSORT(A):
BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A);
for (i = A.length; i >= 1; i++)
{
    exchange A[1] with A[i];
    A.heap-size = A.heap-size - 1; 
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A,1);
}
```

MAX_HEAPIFY is `O(lg n)`.
The book says it runs MAX-HEAPIFY `n` times thus it is `O(n lg n)` time.

But if the heap is shrinking in size by 1 each iteration shouldn't it be `O(lg n!)` ?

It would be `lg 1 + lg 2 ... + lg(n-1) + lg (n) = lg(n!)`, right ?

Comment: In this case I'm adding logarithms of base 2 together so the arguments of the logarithms would multiply together

Comment: O(n log n) and O(log n!) are the same...

Comment: `n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)...*1`  => `n! < n*n*n*... ntimes`  => `n!=O(n^n)` => `O(lg(n!)=O(nlogn)`

Answer (score 10):

Actually it's [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

`O( log(n!) )` = `O(nlogn)`

Comment: So does my statement make sense?
I'm starting to think I just don't understand the textbook